# How to export a text file in Download public storage directory?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a text file in .txt format and also want to save it in DOWNLOAD public directory. How I can do this? Please, help. I was trying in many ways but everyone export in root private directory.

Comment: Please use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, so the *user* can tell you where the *user* wants this content to be saved on the *user's* device.

Comment: Please describe